# How to let my objects get away with arc, 2 problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, automatic-ref-counting

I have an NSObject CardView.

In this Object i have the following Method:

```
-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame andPosition: (NSInteger)pos andValue: (NSInteger)value {
self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
if (self) {

    // IMAGE
    self.frontImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Game_Highlighted.png"]];
    self.backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Game_Black.png"];


    self.backMultiGameImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Game_1.png"];

    self.backMultiGameImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Game_2.png"];

    self.backMultiGameImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Game_3.png"];



    self.circlePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"X" ofType:@"aif"]] error:NULL];
    [self.circlePlayer prepareToPlay];


    self.whiteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_Grey.png"];

    self.flashImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DOT_Game_White.png"];




        NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sounds%ld", (long) (value+1)];
        NSString * strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strName ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL * urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];
        self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:NULL];

    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.image = self.backImage;
    self.value = value;
    self.pos = pos;

}
return self;
}
```

I call this Method in a UIViewController (my gameViewController) with:

```
-(void) generateCardsForLevel1 {


    CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];


}
```

Ok, this happens in a For Loop, for each level about 4 - 18 times. I reuse my gameViewController every time for every level.

At level 9-11 i get one of these 2 exceptions:

sometimes this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>    (loaded)' with name 'waM-3i-9Mb-view-Jua-6a-Qox' and
>   directory 'Main.storyboardc''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x27642137 0x3597fc77 0x2764207d 0x2b04d489 0x2af64ba7 0x2ad9890d 0x2ac7c599 0x2ac7c51d 0x2b2d9dd7
>   0x2af51049 0x2af69fab 0x2af6c0d7 0x2ac89675 0x2af6c00b 0x2ad5cc51
>   0xd08c3 0xd0035 0x2acb0941 0x2acb0559 0x2acb046f 0x2a69f047 0x23c187
>   0x23fe9d 0x27607889 0x27605fa9 0x275519a1 0x275517b3 0x2ed011a9
>   0x2acdc695 0xd79e5 0x35f27aaf) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

or sometimes this:

> : ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed
>   '/Users/Markus/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3420459D-280A-4B0E-84D0-0729B8264014/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F74E13D9-5466-4A82-91E9-900516E0219E/Memory.app/Game_Black.png'
>
> ```
>     error = 24 (Too many open files)
> ```

ARC is on. So my questions are:

1. waM-3i-9Mb-view-Jua-6a-Qox is my View (Jua-6a-Qox) in my gameViewController (waM-3i-9Mb). why does my view crashes?
2. error = 24 (Too many open files): i think ARC can't release the initialized items. but i don't know why. i tried it with:

   ```
   CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] init];

   cv = nil;
   ```

and created

```
-(void) dealloc { 
     NSLog(@"dealloc successful"); }
```

and i get the log output, so it works. but nothing changed. also i tried to nil all out like:

```
    self.frontImage = nil;
    self.backImage = nil;
```

and so on. but the problems are still there.

Comment: BTW do you have anything like Main.storyboardc?

Comment: no, its just a "system typo" i searched for storyboardc but its all correct

Comment: Have you added `dealloc` NSLog you your CardView class to check they are all being deallocated every level? You should count the number created and number deallocated each level to check there are no stragglers. Give each card an index you can print on dealloc. Something is getting left behind which catches up with you eventually.

Comment: You could just make that class not have arc if you don't want to deal with it.  As long as you aren't doing anything too crazy in that ViewController, this will get rid of the error message.  Go to Build Phases tab, then Compile Sources, then find your file and put this as compiler flag: -fno-objc-arc

Comment: tried every hint you gave me, but the problem is still there. @RoryMcKinnel: how should i give every card an index? whats the easiest way?

Comment: You could just add a `@property NSString *cardId` to CardView. When you create one set it to `[NSString stringWithFormat:\@"Level %d, Card:%d",level,card]`. Add `- (void) dealloc {NSLog(\@"CardView deallocated = %\@",self.cardId];` to the CardView class. You should then see what is deallocated as you run or not.

Comment: The most common area I have found for memory not being released is when you capture `self` or an object which has captured `self` in completion handlers or other blocks. Do you have any block based code anywhere where you might be doing this?